# Using readLine() outside a loop

Tags: java, readline

I'm trying to use a readLine() outside a while loop. The input is :

```
4
2 1
1 2 
3 2
2 6 5
3 3
2 4 5
4 2
1 2 4 5
```

(10 lines)
When I do a readLine()  for 10 times, one after the other, I can read all the ten lines. However this only depends on if there's a newline after the last line of input. If there's no explicit newline, it never reads the last line. Is there a workaround? Or should I do a readLine() whithin a for loop only?

Including code:

```
BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String s;
    int lineCount = 0;
    int testCase = 0;
    try {
        if ((s = r.readLine()) != null)
            testCase = Integer.parseInt(s);
        testCase = testCase * 2;
        while (lineCount < testCase) {
            System.out.println("Line Count\t" + lineCount);
            String testCaseString = r.readLine();
            System.out.println(testCaseString);
            String arrayTest = r.readLine();
            System.out.println(arrayTest);
            String bTemp[] = testCaseString.split(" ");
            int k = Integer.parseInt(bTemp[1]);
            String aTemp[] = arrayTest.split(" ");
            int a[] = new int[Integer.parseInt(bTemp[0])];
            int n = 0;
            for (String temp : aTemp) {
                a[n] = Integer.parseInt(temp);
                n++;
            }
            int counter = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                if (counter <= k) {
                    if (a[i] % 2 == 0 && a[i] != 0) {
                        counter++;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (counter == k)
                System.out.println("YES");
            else
                System.out.println("NO");
            lineCount = lineCount + 2;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and the codechef problem I have solved: [PRGIFT](http://www.codechef.com/problems/PRGIFT)

Comment: Hard to say without any code.

Comment: Added code. Please let me know if it's too long and I can cut the logic out.

Comment: The input is 9 lines, actually, both on the problem page and in your question. Do you have an extra line in your input file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the first line with 4, follow 9 lines, you iterate 4 times stepping by 2. That's 8 to me.

One missing.